# List indices must be integers, not object

Tags: python, list

Having a problem with a code for homework. Basically what I'm trying to do is take in a list of objects and pass them to my fire method.

```
def fire(self,targets):
    i = 0
    for i in targets:
        x,y = targets[i].position
        tx,ty = self.position
        d = getDist(targets[i].position, self.position)
```

Whenever I call the fire method and pass in the objects it points me to line 17 which is the `x,y = targets[i].position` line and says "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not Bomber"

Bomber is the name of the class. I call the fire method like this:

```
bOne.fire([bTwo, tOne, tTwo, tThree])
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are looping over the list itself, which means you don't need to use the values as an index:

```
>>> for elem in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
...     print elem
'a'
'b'
'c'
```

In python, the `for` construct doesn't work just with numbers, it works *directly* with the elements of the sequence you are looping over.

Comment: @user1647246: That was the aim, thanks for being frank about it being homework. :-)

Comment: One more thing. If i wanted to compare the first element in the list to the second element would i just add another variable like for elem, elemTwo in ['a', 'b', 'c']?